# Change the value of one array when the other array is sorted in ascending order in Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have two arrays:

- `int[] arr1`
- `int[] arr2`

Both the above have a size of `n` which is a user input.

I need to arrange arr2 in ascending order using java. How do i change the value of arr1 corresponding to the value of `arr2`?

Example(more info):

```
int[] arr1={1,2,3,4,5};
int[] arr2={3,6,5,1,9};
Arrays.sort(arr2);
```

How i want the output:

- arr1={4,1,3,2,5}
- arr2={1,3,5,6,9}

Here arr2 is already sorted

Comment: What do you mean by `How do i change the value of arr1 corresponding to the value of arr2`? You want `arr1` to be sorted? Or arranged in some particular order comparing with `arr2`. I reckon some information is missing. Could you please elaborate. And also, please provide what you've tried so far.

Comment: @iMan It could be better explained, but I think what is desired here is to rearrange both arrays equally, so `arr2` ends sorted. In the example, both have the 4th element first, 1st element second, etc. It is really a bit hard to explain.

Comment: KVilla, show us what you tried so far. You could try sorting arr2 by hand (instead of using that sort method) and then evertime you change something in arr2 you just have to make the same change in arr1.

Comment: @RayO'Kalahjan that makes sense. Lets see if that is what he indeed meant. :)

Comment: Please explain the logic behind what you want to do. It is unclear to me why 4 comes first in the sorted `arr1`.

Comment: Is it that the same permutation has to be applied to arr1? So: In arr2 "1" is sorted from index 3 to index 0 , so in arr1 the value in index 3 shall also be transferred to index 0 ?

Comment: @Fildor, yes, exactly. Like how in excel, we sort data of one column and the other columns also change their order. The arrays are related, so change of index of one must also change the position/index of the other.

Answer (score 0):

If you have no duplicate numbers in the second array like the provided example, you can use `Map`.

At first, take a map. Put *array2* values into `key` and *array1* values into `value` in the map. Then sort the map according to the values. Now if you get the keys from the map, you'll get what you want.

Use [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html). It doesn't need sorting. It enters data such way that guarantees that the map will be in ascending key order.

```
Map<Integer, Integer> m = new TreeMap<>();

int[] arr1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int[] arr2 = {3, 6, 5, 1, 9};

// Put array2 values as key parameter and array1 values as value parameter
for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    m.put(arr2[i], arr1[i]);
}

int i = 0;

// Print the sorted map
for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : m.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("arr1["+ i +"] = " + entry.getValue());
    i++;
}
```

Output:

```
arr1[0] = 4
arr1[1] = 1
arr1[2] = 3
arr1[3] = 2
arr1[4] = 5
```

Comment: What if there are duplicates?

Comment: int[] arr2 = {1, 2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2, 3, 4, 5};
int[] arr1 = {3, 6,1,2,3,4,5,6,7, 5, 1, 9};

Comment: Yes u got it right. I forgot this case. Edited my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is the following:

Create a class that contains two numbers (one from `arr1` and another from `arr2`). Make it implement comparable and compare the second number.

```java
public class Pair implements Comparable<Pair> {

    private Integer e1;
    private Integer e2;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Pair o) {
        return getE1().compareTo(o.getE1());
    }
}
```

In the method, make a list of `Pair` and fill it with the elements of both arrays, then simply sort it with the method in `Collections`.

```java
int[] arr1={1,2,3,4,5};
int[] arr2={3,6,5,1,9};
ArrayList<Pair> list = new ArrayList<Pair>();
for(int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    list.add(new Pair(arr1[i], arr2[i]);
}
Collections.sort(list);
```